# Python Pyinstaller App won't open after zipping, uploading and downloading

Tags: python, download, pycharm, zip, pyinstaller

I've made a python app using pyinstaller - it works great! But when I host it on my google drive for people to download and they try open it it gives the error

> *The application "MyApp" can’t be opened*.

It still has the same app size, thumbnail and works perfectly elsewhere etc but just won't open if its uploaded/downloaded. (This is on a Mac, on PC it seems to be okay).

It's really broken my app. Thoughts?

Comment: Might be something to do with software signing.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I'm not sure what software signing is sorry.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/developer-id/

Comment: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-OSX-Code-Signing

Comment: Did you solve it?